# Are local copy of Costmaps used for recovery behaviours updated in real time?

Tags: ros, navigation, nav-core, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

My ros distribution is ros kinetic.

I am currently implementing a recovery behavior in a similar fashion of the rotate recovery of the nav core.
During the init of the recovery i am doing a local copy of the costmap:

```
world_model_ = new base_local_planner::CostmapModel(*local_costmap_->getCostmap());
```

After that during the execution of the recovery I am doing several calls to footprintCost:

```
double footprint_cost = world_model_->footprintCost(x_cost, y_cost, theta, local_costmap_->getRobotFootprint(), 0.0, 0.0);
```

Is the cost-map interrogated by the footprintCost function updated in real time or is fixed at init time ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343358/are-local-copy-of-costmaps-used-for-recovery-behaviours-updated-in-real-time?/) by [Alrevan](https://answers.ros.org/users/48145/alrevan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2020-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: yes.

Longer answer:  https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/d00067cae219a5ab4486874ccc8912b63291d5d0/base_local_planner/src/costmap_model.cpp#L64

You'll see that you're taking a reference to the costmap on initialization and then working with it. When you `getCost()`, you're getting the current cost of the costmap you referenced at initialization which is continuing to update in a background thread.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-05**:
Would you not want to link to https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/d00067cae219a5ab4486874ccc8912b63291d5d0/base_local_planner/src/costmap_model.cpp#L64 instead?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-02-05**:
Yes :-) sorry, that was a mixture of googling and not looking close enough

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-06**:
Updated the link.